# Python sending email via Gmail failed

Tags: python, gmail

I am using this piece of code:

```
import smtplib

fromaddr = 'fromuser@gmail.com'
toaddrs  = 'myemail@gmail.com'
msg = 'There was a terrible error that occured and I wanted you to know!'


# Credentials (if needed)
username = 'myusername'
password = 'passwd'

# The actual mail send
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com',465)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(username,password)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
server.quit()
```

I am receiving this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Python34/sendemail.py",
>   line 15, in 
>       server.starttls() File "C:\Python34\lib\smtplib.py", line 673, in starttls
>       raise SMTPException("STARTTLS extension not supported by server.") smtplib.SMTPException: STARTTLS extension not supported by server.

When I do exculde server.starttls() I am receiving different error message about authentication. I have another price of code when I am accessing Gmail via web browser using webdriver and credentials works, so I copied and pasted to this code to make sure that credentials are correct.

I can't figure out why this is not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using port 587 instead? Port 465 is SMTPS which expects the SSL handshake on connection and doesn't do starttls. So, the relevant error message is actually the one about the failed authentication.

Comment: It doesn't work gives me SSL error

Answer (score 3):

you'll have to see [here](http://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) as well

use port 587

```
server=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
server.starttls()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sending via Gmail works for me when using this code. Note that I use `smtplib.SMTP()` as opposed to `smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com',465)`. **Also try to use port 587 and not 465.**

```
server = smtplib.SMTP()
server.connect(server, port)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(username, password)
server.sendmail(send_from, send_to, msg)
server.close()
```

Though I do find that using the `emails` library is much easier.

Comment: Your port number is not 465, correct? Your sample code does not disclose that.

Comment: You are right, I added the port number which is 587 to my answer.

Comment: If I change a port to 587 it doesn't work, gives me SSL error

Comment: Also if I do your way smtplib.SMTP() <- empty and than server.connect it going bananas: ile "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 533, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

Answer (score 0):

Please, try [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail). Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer, but I feel like it can help everyone out!

It really provides a lot of defaults: I'm quite sure you'll be able to send an email directly with:

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP(username, password)
yag.send(to_addrs, contents = msg)
```

You'll have to install `yagmail` first with either:

```
pip install yagmail  # python 2
pip3 install yagmail # python 3
```

Once you will want to also embed html/images or add attachments, you'll **really** love the package!

It will also make it a lot safer by preventing you from having to have your password in the code.

Answer (score 0):

It's either you use smtplib.SMTP() then starttls() (which I don't recommend), or you use smtplib.SMTP_SSL() alone ( dont't use starttls() after that)